# What is the difference between a random-effects regression and the negative binominal regression

Tags: random-effects-model, poisson-regression

My question is related to the topic if my data is overdispersed  is random-effects poisson regression a suitable option?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail on what you are asking about. Your title asks to compare random effects regression - do you mean linear, Poisson, or negative binomial? Your question comment asks about overdispersion. I assume you are trying to compare Poisson to negative binomial, but can you provide more details on your situation and what you want to learn about?

Comment: Hey, i do have panel data on 23 countries and 26 years. My data is poisson distributed. My data is also overdispersed. Now,  i tried to figure out the best option for my regression analysis. During literature research i got confused where the difference between "poisson random effects" and  "negative binominal regression". As i understood the random effect in poisson adds a degree of freedom just as the same as in negative binominal distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confounding the purpose for random effects and negative binomial regression.

**Overdispersion**: Poisson models assume the mean and variance are equal. When the variance is greater than the mean, the data are said to be overdispersed. In my experience (admittedly not that lengthy in this area) I've never seen evenly dispersed count data. The most common, and I believe the best, way to deal with overdispersion is to use a negative binomial model, which adds a parameter for dispersion. The interpretation of all other model parameters are the same.

**Intra-group clustering**: Random effects are used for a lot of purposes, but one of the most common is to account for clustering of observations within groups. The idea is that two units that belong to the same group are more alike than two units not in the group. Regression models typically assume independently distributed observations - intra-group clustering or correlation violates that assumption and can affect your variance estimation. There are many methods to adjust for this, random effects being one of them and maybe one of the most common these days. With your panel data you likely have two sources of clustering: within a time period (cross-sectional) and within units (longitudinal). There is no fast and easy way to decide which random effects to include and how to specify them.  For example, you could have time as a linear and squared term, and have a random effect for each country. Or you may run some tests and and do some hard thinking and decide you want fixed effects for countries, rather than random. That eats up more DF, but it also may make more sense depending on how you conceive of the model.

I would recommend looking into longitudinal or panel texts to figure out what is most appropriate in your case.You can certainly post further questions to CV, but I would recommend you come with specific questions, rather than broad recommendations for an approach.

One last thing to keep in mind: Panel data may require incorporating lagged terms, and thinking about temporal dynamics (differencing, stationarity, etc.). This can get fairly complicated, so definitely do some reading on all of that. I'm not sure how advanced count models have gotten with dealing with this - if you can approximate your data with a normal distribution you will be in better shape, so take a look at a histogram and the skewness of your data - maybe applying a log transformation would help.